# Infinitesimal definition of the Poisson process problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

The infinitesimal definition of the Poisson process is given as follows

$$P(N(t+h)=n|N(t)=m)= \begin{cases} 
      \lambda h +o(h) & \text{if } n=m+1\\
      1- \lambda h +o(h) &\text{if } n=m \\
      o(h) & \text{if } n \ge m+2 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases} $$
Here $N(t)$ counts the number of arrivals in the interval $[0,t]$. Also it has rate parameter $\lambda$.

The problem we have is as follows: "Customers arrive at a ticket office as a Poisson process of rate $λ.$ Suppose that
each customer buys a ticket for $£2$. Let $X(t)$ be the amount of money (in
pounds) collected by the ticket office up to time $t$.
Write down an expression for $P(X(t + h) = n | X(t) = m)$ analogous to the
infinitesimal description of the Poisson process. "

I am finding this quite tricky as I don't really like working with the infinitesimal definition. My thought process is as follows. $X(t)$ must have parameter $2 \lambda$ as for every arrival the customer spends $£2$, then I think the expression would look like this:
$$P(X(t + h) = n | X(t) = m) = \begin{cases} 
      2\lambda h +o(h) & \text{if } n=m+1\\
      1- 2\lambda h +o(h) &\text{if } n=m \\
      o(h) & \text{if } n \ge m+2 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases} $$
This seems somehow "too simple" does anyone know how I should proceed?

Comment: No, the rate does not change but the amount of money $X(t)=2N(t)$.

Comment: @KBS So how exactly can I incorporate that constant $2$ into the 'new' definition?

Comment: You do not need to do that, as you can just work with the random variable $X$, which is a function of $N$. But you have that $\mathbb P \big(X(t+h)=n+2|X(t)=n\big) = \lambda h + o(h)$ and $\mathbb P \big(X(t+h)=n|X(t)=n\big) = 1-\lambda h + o(h)$.

Comment: @KBS I do not understand where you have got those equations from.

Comment: It comes from the definition of $X$ and $N$. Write down the diagram of the Markov chain for $X$, place the arrows and then place the rates.

Comment: A Poisson process isn't a Markov chain though?

Comment: It is one of the simplest Markov chains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P(X(t + h) = n | X(t) = m) = \begin{cases} 
      \lambda h +o(h) & \text{if } n=m+2\\
      1- \lambda h +o(h) &\text{if } n=m \\
      o(h) & \text{if } n \ge m+2 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases} $$

Note that $X(t)$ characterizes the state of the Markov chain at time $t$.

The state increments by 2 at each transition.  The rates remain the same.

The ingredients for a Markov process are

- states
- state variables
- transition rates

you have only one state variable, namely, the cost.  You have infinite states, and the transition rates are defined above. From each state, you have only one possible transition, namely, to increment the state variable by 2 units.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will ask, is it also impossible to have a case where the amount of money we have increases by an odd amount? As we can only increment it 2 at a time. I.e. could we assign $0$ probability to the case where $n=m+2k+1$ for some $k \ge 0$.

Comment: this is already taken into account in the case "otherwise"

Comment: Ah of course. Good point. Many thanks.